# Cannot set Parameter size when using adLongVarChar in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a function that makes a call to a SQL Server database to return a `String` value. Previously, expected string values were fairly short, but as the character length can exceed 255 on occasion, I have changed the SQL field type in the table to `nvarchar(MAX)`.

In the project, I have altered the code to use `adLongVarChar` instead of `adVarChar` and need to specify the length. As there is no length, I know for Input parameters, `-1` is the correct length to use. However, when using this as an Output parameter, I receive Run-Time Error 3708 - 'Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.'

What is the correct syntax to construct the paramter?

Code below:

```vb
Public Function getStatus() As String
    Dim db As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sp As ADODB.Command
    Dim rp1 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim rp2 As ADODB.Parameter
    
    '// Data declarations
    Set db = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set sp = New ADODB.Command
    Set rp1 = sp.CreateParameter("@ksActive", adBoolean, adParamOutput)
    Set rp2 = sp.CreateParameter("@ksMsg", adLongVarChar, adParamOutput, -1)
        
    '// Data connection initialisation
    db.Open dbString
        With sp
            .ActiveConnection = db
            .CommandText = "dbo.TestProcedureName"
            .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
            .Parameters.Append rp1                               '// This works fine 
            .Parameters.Append rp2                               '// Error occurs here
            .Execute
        End With
        
        getStatus = rp2.Value
End Function
```

Comment: _As there is no length, I know for Input parameters, -1 is the correct length to use_ Eh, where have you found that? Usually you can just omit the length just as you do for the other parameter. Also, `nvarchar(MAX)` corresponds with `LongVarWChar` and `adLongVarChar` corresponds with `varchar(MAX)`.

Comment: @ErikA - I didn't realise you didn't have to include the `-1` - that usually seems to work when using it as the length for an Input value. Omitting the -1 in this case, still doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you try `adLongVarWChar`?

Comment: Yes I did @June7 - omitting the size causes the failure and adding -1 or 0 also causes a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL/DR: Use `.Parameters.Refresh` and `.NamedParameters = True` to define output (return) parameters in MS Access ADODB.

I just came across this and had this same problem. I found a hint on [MSDN "What is the ADO DataType for nVarchAR(max)"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac06f814-1814-4861-b2cd-8d5e507a7ee3/what-is-the-ado-datatype-for-nvarcharmax?forum=sqldataaccess). For whatever reason, you MUST include an initial value with the length (at least in Access VBA) for long value parameters in Access ADO. I found adding `NULL` works just fine to satisfy it, especially when you set the values later for stored commands.

NOTE: This will only work for input values (as shown here, outputs cannot be defined like this)

```
 '  Note: only works for output params.
Set rp2 = sp.CreateParameter("@ksMsg", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, -1, NULL)
```

#### Output Parameter definition:

Using OP's names:

```
Public Function getStatus() As String
    Dim db As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sp As ADODB.Command
    Dim rp1 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim rp2 As ADODB.Parameter
    
    '// Data declarations
    Set db = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set sp = New ADODB.Command
   
    '// Data connection initialisation
    db.Open dbString
    Dim sp As ADODB.Command
    
    With sp
        .ActiveConnection = db
        .CommandText = "dbo.TestProcedureName"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .Parameters.Refresh
        .NamedParameters = True
        Set rp1 = .Parameters("@ksActive")
        Set rp2 = .Parameters("@ksMsg")
        ' Set outputs to null because they're cached, and if your 
        ' second call returns nothing, you'll get the prior call's results.
        rp1.Value = Null
        rp2.Value = Null
        .Execute
    End With
    
    getStatus = rp2.Value
End Function
```

You need to use `sp.Parameters.Refresh` to define output parameters for stored procedures.  After scouring the internet, it appears that there's an issue with  using MS Access ADODB `adLongVarWChar` (or any long / wide return variable) and `adParamOutput` or `adParamInputOutput` and defining them explicitly.

I have found the only way to get Output Parameters to work is to use `.Parameters.Refresh`; once I did that, it works just fine (and returns correctly).

Just be sure to clear them out before executing (set outputs to null) or you'll get the previously cached result back (and it will send you on a wild goose chase).

Comment: Amazing. Felt like the good old days having such a clear and concise answer! Thank you for taking the time to put this here - that absolutely sorted the problem!

Comment: You're very welcome! Thanks for the check! Tis a small price to pay for the support I've gleaned off SO...

Comment: Couldn't agree more @hecon5 - sadly it seems to be a dying belief... thanks again!